# Wikipedia geolocation doesnt give all the closest page

Tags: api, geolocation, wikipedia

Hello Im trying to read all the Wikipedia page that are close to my location , Im using the city where Im living.

As you can see in the result isnt https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=52633874 is a Temple that is in the location that Im searching.

Anyone know why doesnt appear?

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&format=json&gscoord=8.411389|99.966667&gsradius=10000&gslimit=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably no one has geotagged it yet - compare [Nakhon Si Thammarat Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakhon_Si_Thammarat_Province) (the first search result) which has coordinates in the upper right corner of the article. I'd guess that's due to it setting `{{coord|...|display=inline,title}}` in its coordinate template, but I'm not really familiar with English Wikipedia geotemplates.

Comment: Thanks , It was that I change the format in the wikipedia page and now is working